# Mura CMS - Modifying the "Format" CKEditor dropdown

Tags: ckeditor, mura

I want to modify the "Format" dropdown for CKEditor within Mura, because I don't like the way Mura renames the headings. For example, an `<h2>` element is renamed to "Heading", and an `<h3`> element is renamed to "Heading 2". I get why they did this, because the `<h1>` is reserved for the page title, but it's confusing for content editors and accessibility.

I want to remove this renaming feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the naming being used (like "Heading 1") is part of the CKEditor itself ([reference](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_format)).

[image]

As far as which HTML tag is actually used for those formats, Mura allows you to customize that. Look at the `contentRenderer.cfc` file under your theme's folder. Within that file they are setting variables that are used to customize the editor and page layouts. Specifically this section ([reference](http://docs.getmura.com/v6/back-end/site-contentrenderercfc/available-renderer-settings/)):

```
// The following settings allow developers to change logical page structure. 
// For example, some developers prefer H1 tags for their page titles, 
// some prefer H2 tags - you can adjust this here:

this.headline='h2';
this.subHead1='h3';
this.subHead2='h4';
this.subHead3='h5';
this.subHead4='h6';
```

I'm not 100% sure but I think those settings are also used within the CKEditor in Mura.